# Strange order of output of linq query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, group-by

I have a massive of int values.

```
int[] numbers= {5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0};
```

I divide this numbers on the modulo:

```
 var numberGroups=from n in numbers group n by n%5  into g select new { Remainder=g.Key, Numbers=g};
```

and I have such strange order of results:

```
  // 0, 4, 1, 3, 2
```

In my honour opinion the order should be:

```
  //0, 4, 3, 1, 2
```

As the first number which can be divided by 5 is 5. // 0

The second number which can be divided by 5 is 9. // 4

The third number which can be divided by 5 is 8. // 3

The fourth number which can be divided by 5 is 6. // 1

The fifth number which can be divided by 5 is 7. // 2

I have such presentation of work group by. Where am I wrong?

Questions:

1. Why does linq change order?
2. Why do I have such strange order?

Comment: The order you're seeing is what I would expect; why do you think it should be different? I think you're making an incorrect assumption about how GroupBy works.

Comment: Your explanation of your expect order is strange, all numbers are dividable by 5, they are just not cleanly dividable. Also your doing modulo not division, so your assumption of number greater than 5 grouping first is wrong.

Comment: @Simeon Pilgrim, thanks! Make your answer, I will mark it.

Comment: Are you saying make my above comment regarding division verse modulo is the root cause of the confusion? Thus I should make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groups are added in the order that they are needed. Which is the order of the input to the group clause. Given 5 is the first value, the 0 group is created first... this can been seen with the following code examples.

With this code:

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

var numberGroups = from n in numbers group n by n % 5 into g select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

foreach(var ng in numberGroups)
{
    Console.Write("{0} - ", ng.Remainder);
    foreach (var v in ng.Numbers)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0}", v);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I get

```
0 - 5 0
4 - 4 9
1 - 1 6
3 - 3 8
2 - 7 2
```

which makes be believe there is no sort on the group operation, it is rather collecting the number in the order they are found, the first number 5, results in remainder 0 so the first output bucket is 0. We can test this by putting the 9 first and we get

```
4, 0, 1, 3, 2
```

To prove they add added to the buckets in the order they are processed, using these numbers

```
int[] numbers = { 15, 24, 31, 43, 59, 68, 76, 87, 92, 100 };
```

we get

```
0 -  15 100
4 -  24 59
1 -  31 76
3 -  43 68
2 -  87 92
```

15 is added first new slot 0, 24 is new slot 4, 31 net slot 1, 43 is new slot 3, 59 next 4 value, 68 is next 3 slot value, 76 next 1 slot, 87 new slot 2, 92 next 2, 100 next 0

to prove this more use:

```
int[] numbers = { 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105 };
```

we get

```
0 -  15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95 105
```

It might not be how you want it, but is makes 100% sense how/why it's happens.

Comment: Yeah, the first number is correct. But the next values are not situated in order which they located in a massive.

Comment: They are exactly in the order supplied.

Comment: Ok. What about int[] oo={16, 24, 1, 2, 4, 58, 33, 46, 64, 75};

Comment: with out running, 1,4,2,3,0, what would you expect?